# OpenOCD child process termination: Wrong device detected

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, jtag, stm32f10x

**Setup**

I have an STM32F103C8T6 minimal eval board (see [STM32F103C8T6](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/stm32f103c8t6-stm32f103-stm32f1-stm32-system-board-learning-board-evaluation-kit-development-board/32817069163.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4FmVO6)).

And I'm using an ST link like the picture below.

I installed System Workbench for Eclipse. I created my own project (C++, Empty Project, toolchains: Ac6 STM 32 MCU GCC), 
Series: STM32F1, Mcu: STM32F103C8Tx, Core: ARM Cortex-M3, Package: LQFP48, Memory ram: Size 0x5000, memory ROM: size 0x10000.

**Code**

The code contains a system_stm32f10x.c file which was generated (or automatically included) by the IDE.

The program compiles ok:

---

```
  * @file    main.c
  * @author  Ac6
  * @version V1.0
  * @date    01-December-2013
  * @brief   Default main function.
  ******************************************************************************
*/


#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include <stm32f10x_rcc.h>

void delay(int counter)
{
    volatile int i;
    for (i = 0; i < counter * 10000; i++) {}
}

int main(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

    GPIO_StructInit(&gpio);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_13);

    while (1)
    {
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_13); // LED ON
        delay(400);
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_13); // LED OFF
        delay(400);
    }
}
```

**Upload by OpenSTM32**

When I create a Run configuration (no changes made), and select Run I get the following error (in console):

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-dev-00302-gc211ca5-dirty (2017-07-03-10:41)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_assert_srst
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 950 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v17 API v2 SWIM v4 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : vid/pid are not identical: 0x0483/0x374B 0x0483/0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.231135
Info : STM32F103C8Tx.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
adapter speed: 950 kHz
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted
TARGET: STM32F103C8Tx.cpu - Not halted
in procedure 'program' 
in procedure 'reset' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 478
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'

** Unable to reset target **
shutdown command invoked
```

**Connections**

- STlink SWDIO pin 2 -> pin 7 of JTAG
- STlink GND pin 4 GND -> pin 4 of JTAG
- STlink SWCLK pin 6 -> pin 9 of JTAG
- USB -> USB ( STlink 3.3V pin 8 not connected, neither all other STlink pins)

**Schematic**

[image]
 [image: STLink]

**Debug configuration file**

```
# This is an F103C8T6_Simple board with a single STM32F103C8Tx chip
#
# Generated by System Workbench for STM32
# Take care that such file, as generated, may be overridden without any early notice. Please have a look to debug launch configuration setup(s)

source [find interface/stlink.cfg] 

set WORKAREASIZE 0x5000

transport select "hla_swd"

set CHIPNAME STM32F103C8Tx

# Enable debug when in low power modes
set ENABLE_LOW_POWER 1

# Stop Watchdog counters when halt
set STOP_WATCHDOG 1

# STlink Debug clock frequency
set CLOCK_FREQ 4000

# use hardware reset, connect under reset
# connect_assert_srst needed if low power mode application running (WFI...)
reset_config srst_only srst_nogate connect_assert_srst
set CONNECT_UNDER_RESET 1

source [find target/stm32f1x.cfg]
```

**Run configurations screen**

[image]

**Update**

I could send a program via the Link utility, see below. I don't see a blinking light, but maybe the program is incorrect.

However, this way is not very comfortable (and I don't see any program running). Also, I still cannot debug this way.

[image]

[image: Program upload/verify]

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

See my answer (to help others with the similar problem)

Thank you all very much for your answers and numerous useful remarks.

Comment: You really need to include a schematic of your development board, and specify the name or include the text of your openocd adapter script.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I added the schematics (sorry for the bad picture, I have not so good light here).

Comment: Download the [ST-Link Utility](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-link004.html) tool and check that your ST-Link is working at all.

Comment: Your hardware does not seem to use the RST line, thus you would need "reset_config none".

Comment: @Turbo I don't know yet wat reset_config non means, but I will this evening read more about all reset issues/handling

Comment: @Bence Kaulics ... that one worked, I can even upload (see screenshots at the end), but I don't see any LED blinking.

Comment: @BenceKaulics ... I succeeded in getting a LED blink ... thanks for your idea.

Comment: @TurboJ Thanks for the good comment, I changed it to software reset (or something, and it works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Connections made: STlink SWDIO pin 2 -> pin 7 of JTAG STlink GND pin 4 GND -> pin 4 of JTAG STlink SWCLK pin 6 -> pin 9 of JTAG STlink 3.3V pin 8 -> pin 2 of JTAG

<s>Resetting doesn't mysteriously happen. It is actually a direct connection into MCU reset pin from the jtag/swd which is missing in your configuration.</s>

edit: That was wrong. See comment of Chris.

*** update ***

Emulation reset needs correct openocd config parameters, which are set for hardware reset currently. "srst" is all about system reset which is not about emulation. Also read the manual on the github carefully: Author makes the reset manually, pushing the reset button before issuing reset command and releasing within the wait-the-reset period of openocd.

Also removing the parameter "reset on connect" from the config file may ease things for such manual resetting.

So, the solution is either manual resetting, or correct parameters for emulation (If your chip actually has it; I had to strike the text above because of the conceptional error, I don't know if your chip has it) or adapting your stlink's reset signal into board.

Comment: Not necessarily.  STM32's also support a command reset.  Pretty much the only time you need the hardware reset is if there is a program loaded which disables (re-purposes) the SWD pins.

Comment: I got the information from https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32/wiki/Programming-an-STM32F103XXX-with-a-generic-%22ST-Link-V2%22-programmer-from-Linux ... where I also connected 3.3V from the ST Link to the JTAG (pin 1) because I don't use USB.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be trying to power the target board from the SWD adapter.  It looks intended for 5v USB power itself, and backpowering the unknown internal regulator is a dubious thing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I now put it via a USB cable, but still does not work (I adapter the question).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, see the update.

Comment: @Ayhan which manual on GitHub you are referring to (to read)? In the link I used I skipped some parts related with the terminal (since I don't use Linux). Also I think I miss some configuration GDB options.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, it is the link above in your comment (wiki). Search "reset" word in the document. I didn't understand why the reset line is not being used.

Comment: @Ayhan ... yes of course (about the wiki link), sorry for the stupid question of me. I will check it this evening (not knowing there could be such much problems with just a reset ... used to Arduino too much).

Comment: @Ayhan I tried to continue the github manual, howevever, it is for unix, so the reset part couldn't be done.

Comment: @Ayhan I could upload via the STLink, but still I don't know if my program runs (at least it doesn't blink a LED)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I presume that you have either reset or powered off/on the board after programming. Programming seems to be OK. But, about the program, anything could be wrong and maybe it is all OK but the LED port is wrong. So, debugging is mandatory now and you have not solved the reset issue. This is painful. I advice you to use stlink-integrated boards like stm32f3/4 discovery and better tutorials. For example, this seems to be good but outdated: http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com.tr/2012/09/stm32f4discovery-development-with-gcc.html

Comment: @Ayhan .. I have reset it, but now it's not even needed, I'm trying some blink 'variations'and it works instantly. It's very nice to be able to debug too (not possible on an Arduino). Maybe I should started with the discovery, however, it seems to work now. I'm very sorry I had to ask all these (for most) trivial questions and hope I can continue myself now (or have more 'real' questions). Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Ayhan And thanks for the link ... I will check into it soon.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, I really appreciate you jailbreaking the arduino :-) You don't have to be sorry at all, these were all valid and fine questions. I am glad you solved the problems, keep up the good work.

Comment: @Ayhan ... thanks ... I found a book so from now on I hope I can find more through books regarding programming, but with installation/tools etc. I really needed some help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved.

It is fixed by going to the Run Configurations, Debugger tab, Debugger tab, Mode Setup, Reset Mode: Change to Software system reset.

The underlying problem is that my STLink is V2, not V2.1 and this does not have an hardware reset.

Comment: No, your stick has a hardware reset output on pin 1, you just didn't connect it to the target, and don't need to if you use soft reset.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What is the benefit of a hardware reset? Since this seems to work fine.

Comment: The software reset won't work if the SWD pins have been disabled.  In addition to software which does this intentionally, these chips seem to occasionally get there as a result of a failed firmware load.  Asserting reset in conjunction with the establishment of the SWD connection can help cut that off before it takes effect, leaving the debugger in control.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't understand everything that you wrote. I connected the SWD pins (afik). I noticed sometimes the IDE does not see the STM32 anymore, I just remove the USB power and restart it and it works... Or I press the button RST myself ... that would work well enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your OpenOCD config file has an incorrect ProductID number.  This number refers to the ST-LINK clone adapter you are using, not your specific microcontroller.

See this from your OpenOCD Console:

> Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v17 API v2 SWIM v4 VID 0x0483 PID **0x3748**
>
> Info : vid/pid are not identical: 0x0483/**0x374B** 0x0483/0x3748

Notice the difference that I've highlighted.  It's hard to tell the difference between an 8 and a B sometimes!

Since the ST-LINK clones should work the same, I doubt that this is your problem. But I'll leave the info here in case it helps somebody.

Comment: The PID here is that of the stlink (clone) SWD adapter, not the target MCU.  There are several different PIDs, mostly they work the same way.

Comment: I cannot find any of these numbers, except in the log file.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thanks; of course you are correct. I'll leave my answer (after I tweak it) in case it helps somebody...

Comment: @MichelKeijzers You can find the OCD config file location by looking at the "Debugger" tab of the Run Configurations screen in Eclipse.  There is a "Config option" which looks like `-f filename.cfg`. It likely ends in .cfg, but it may be different. Also, give it a try with a Debug Configuration instead of a Run Configuration.

Comment: Command reset not always works. I can't figure when, but sometimes i cant program and debug without it and without disabling the pins

Comment: @bitsmack ... I think I found it, couldn't find the -f but found a configuration file. I added it in the question.

Comment: @bitsmack ... I think I don't have the -f options since I don't have the GDB options in my Run configurations.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers You added a screenshot of the"Main" tab of the Run Configurations window.  Can you also add a screenshot of the "Debugger" tab?

Comment: @bitsmack oops... I updated it.

Comment: @bitsmack I found the -f in the github but I cannot execute those command since it is written for Linux and I have Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To work with ARM chips on Eclipse I use https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/ myself.

The configuration for STM32F103C8T6 using an ST-Link stick using that eclipse plugin would be

`-f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f1x.cfg`

The PID 0x374B is for ST-Link V2.1. The Chinese sticks are ST-Link V2. So you have selected the wrong debugger interface. As you use a different eclipse plugin, I don't know where and how to configure that, but have a look at the selected debugger interface.

Comment: Thanks ... I couldn't find the -f but I have changed the option for software reset, now it looks like:  # use software system reset
reset_config none

Comment: One other thing, I see your ST-Link is running firmware V17. I would recommend to update the firmware ( http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-link007.html ) ( Updating works fine on clones, I have a dozen of them and never had problems )

Comment: Good point and indeed, the ST Link Utility already mentioned it... I now have v27: Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v27 API v2 SWIM v6 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748